# How to add objects to vectors correctly, without calling destructor two times

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I am trying to create list of existing objects in vector. Here is what I have so far:

```
   void Program::addClient(string name){
      vector<Client> *ptr = &(impl->clients);
      Client cl(name);
      ptr->push_back(cl);
   }
```

The problem is that destructor is going to be called two times: first, when method addClient ends and second time, when destructor of this methods class will be called. Because of that, I get an error (obviously). So I thought of writing something like this:

```
   void Program::addCategory(string name){
      vector<Category> *ptr = &(impl->categories);
      Category *c = new Category(name);
      ptr->push_back(c);
   }
```

By doing so, I believe, I would get rid of destructor problem, but there is another problem. My IDE throws an error at sign `->` between `ptr` and `push_back`, saying "no instance of overload function".

What I should do and maybe you have any tips?

Comment: If `Client` is correctly copyable and/or movable, then creating and destroying the temporary won't cause an error. If it's not, then it should be.

Comment: What does the declaration of `Client` look like?

Comment: I can show you full code of Client.cpp here: http://pastebin.com/Hnfg0vKY
Maybe I should try to reload the copying constructor? I am not sure, really, what I should do...

Comment: You should use `std::shared_ptr<Client::Inner>` for your `i` pointer

Comment: @Erbureth thank you for the tip, but since I am a student at university, I have to program by strict rules (we had an example about this)... I will keep in mind about this, though. Thanks :)

Comment: In that case you have to implement reference counting by yourself and call `delete i;` only when the counter reaches zero.

Comment: @Fractal: If you're not allowed to use smart pointers then read up on the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722) and give your class a copy constructor and copy-assignment operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to add objects to vectors correctly, without calling destructor two times

With `emplace_back`:

```
ptr->emplace_back(name);
```

> The problem is that destructor is going to be called two times ... Because of that, I get an error (obviously).

This should not cause an error for a well behaved class. If calling `push_back` is causing you problems, that hints at something wrong with the `Client` class. Make sure it is correctly copyable and assignable.

Comment: If the original code doesn't work for the OP, then she has bigger problems, though...

Comment: @KerrekSB I was going by the title of the question. I couldn't make much sense out of the question itself so I stopped reading.

Comment: @juanchopanza - If you are not able to understand question and you are posting answer to a question, which you don't understand, then you are just a spammer, who should be thrown out from this community...

Comment: @Fractal As I said, I am answering the title of the question, and I am far from being a spammer.

Comment: The problem with the `push_back` is in the second example, not the first.  And it is that he has a vector of `Category` objects, but is trying to push back a pointer to a `Category` object.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I thought the only problem with the first example was undesired destructor calls.  I didn't notice the *"Because of that, I get an error (obviously)."* -- Which is a funny statement, because it's not at all obvious that there should be an error because of that. There obviously should *not* be an error there, unless the class is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your misconception

> The problem is that destructor is going to be called two times: first, when method addClient ends and second time, when destructor of this methods class will be called.

The above is NOT a problem.  When you insert an object into a `std::vector<Client>`, you are inserting a copy. The destructor gets run twice because after the copy is made, there are two objects.

If this is in fact causing you an error, it is fairly likely that `Client` is not properly copyable, and you need to either make it copyable or reconsider how you're using it.